# If div contains word "example" , then addClass display none to another div

Tags: jquery, if-statement, contains

I am trying to hide a `div`, if a specific word is inside another `div`.

```
if (jQuery("div.contactUs:contains('contact')")) {
jQuery(".hideThis").css("display","none");
}
```

But it does not seem to work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to check the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) of the returned jQuery object:

```
if (jQuery("div.contactUs:contains('contact')").length) {
    jQuery(".hideThis").css("display","none");
}
```

The reason for this is the jQuery returns an object, even if no matching elements are found, and that will never evaluate to `false`.

Also note that you can use [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) instead of `css`, just to make your code a little bit shorter:

```
if (jQuery("div.contactUs:contains('contact')").length) {
    jQuery(".hideThis").hide();
}
```

Comment: GREAT thanks James, it works like a charm. Thanks for the explanation. Now I know... :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this, This could show **[how it works](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/uREUT/2/)**

```
if (jQuery("div.contactUs").text().indexOf('contact') != -1) {

jQuery(".hideThis").css("display","none");

}
```